# Data sharing across subdomains

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, conventions

I am developing a react app. The idea is to host different components of the app individually under the same domain (but different subdomains). How would this affect the efficiency of the application overall?

Also, I am hoping to use cookies to get the data transferred across the subdomains?
Are there any other better alternatives? On my system, I tried doing it with `window.postMessage` (from localhost:3000 to localhost:3001) but it didn't seem to work.